# Can you set the src of an input image using CSS?

Tags: css

Can you set the src of an input image using CSS?

This has to work in IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

All you can do is define a `background-image` URL but that is different from a proper `<img>` in so many ways.

Why do you need this? Maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: I have a <input type=image src="..." /> for icons, and want to move the hard coded image url/filenames into css.

Comment: if you know the images' dimensions in advance, you can use @BalusC's solution. If you don't, you can't.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `<input type="submit" class="foo">` instead of `<input type="image" src="foo.png">`.

E.g.

```html
<input type="submit" name="save" value="" class="mybutton" />
```

with for example

```
.mybutton {
    border: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url('foo.png');
}
```

The `<input type="image">` is meant to have sort of an image map as button. When submitted, it sends a `name.x` and `name.y` parameter to the server side which denotes the exact location where the client has pressed on the image map. This has likely not your interest here. You just want a submit button with a background image.

Comment: Doesn't changing it to type submit have ramifications when the user hits 'enter'?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it without changing `type` of your `input`. But if you have to use image type input then there is a hack that I used before.

Set `src` of your `input` to a 1 by 1 pixel transparent PNG file and then use `background-image` to set the image via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking sounds like 'inline images'.  It's not generally a preferred method, but apparently there are some practical uses for it if you are trying to avoid caching of that image.

I borrowed the below code from the following link to give you an example:
http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/

```
ul {list-style:none;}
ul > li {
margin:0 0 .1em;
background:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/) 
top left no-repeat; )
height:14px;
text-indent:1.5em;
}
</style>
```