# set src as background in css

Tags: html, css

I need to create app with using input as checkbox and have html look like following with src for different background. How can i set up the src part under css file instead of inline style?

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="body">
    <input class="checkbox" type="image" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/learning-area/master/html/forms/image-type-example/login.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you set the src of an input image using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196121/can-you-set-the-src-of-an-input-image-using-css)

Comment: can't set background for the input type="checkbox" directly, so we need to use the label to set a background image, check this link https://jsfiddle.net/s4nr6q3d/